# "Room ahead" vs "Head room"

Tags: differences

Consider the following sentences:

> I'm not sure if I still have some room ahead.

And:

> I'm not sure if I still have some head room.

Besides being shorter, and the order of words, what is the difference between both ways?

Which way should I use and in which circunstances?

Comment: Room ahead suggests room (space/time) ahead of you. Headroom refers to room above your head.

Comment: @Josh61 Can you **please** put that in an answer, please? If possible, can you add some examples to show the difference?

Comment: They mean entirely different things.

Comment: Note that "headroom" is very often used in a metaphorical sense, whereas the metaphorical use of "room ahead" is much rarer.

Comment: @HotLicks I had no idea of that. Sadly, it seems I do it all wrong since sometimes I mix both. :/ God, I shouldn't have slept on my English classes!

Comment: "... *in* your English classes" ;)  (Note that most English speakers are quite tolerant of butchered English, so long as the speaker is making an effort.  And minor things like confusing "headroom" and "room ahead" rarely cause serous misunderstandings.)

Comment: @HotLicks Is my English *THAT* bad? If I didn't slept *on* (just joking!) my English classes, I would notice the difference. But for over 5 years my attention was more focused on what I didn't knew (in(?) my first English test on 10th grade, I've scored 0.5 out of 20, I've scored 0 out of 20 on my 3rd test). And I had terrible teachers. I try to have a perfect English. But, if I were comparing my "butchered" English with people who live here in Portugal for 40 years, I would say that I'm doing perfectly fine. Most of them can't understand that objects have gender and we don't have the 'it'.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly adapting the first definition of the single noun *room* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) yields this definition of *room ahead*:

> an extent of space [in front of one] ... sufficient or available for something.

For example, you might say, "I think there is room ahead for my car to pass the slow car in front of me before any oncoming vehicles appear."

*Headroom*, meanwhile, has its own entry in the dictionary:

> vertical space in which to to stand, sit, or move

For example, you might say, "This compact car has so little headroom that my hair brushes the ceiling every time I turn my head."

(This is essentially a restatement of Josh61's comment from two months ago.)

Comment: And a nice restatement! Thank you! Sadly, I don't believe you'll have many upvotes. :/

Answer (score 0):

Headroom is generally used to refer the room needed to pass under or thru something. E.g. you're driving a double-decker bus, which is 14 feet high, towards a bridge, and there's a sign saying "Max headroom 12 feet".  Better turn round.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering. But there are 2 issues with your answer: 1 - You misspelled 'though'. 2 - You only address 1/4th of the question.

Comment: Sorry, Ismael, I should probably have put that as a comment, trying to expand on what Josh61 said about headroom.  I didn't misspell 'though'  -  I *spelt* 'through' as 'thru'.  Quite normal, I think.

Comment: I never saw it outside 'lolcat' text and memes. But, according to http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thru it is a simplified way of spelling 'through' (I misspelled it above, I ate the 'r'). But if you incorporate the content on Josh61's comment, I can upvote. So far, I don't see enough material to upvote, but you have more than enough to do not downvote.

Comment: Sorry, Ismael I'm new to Stack Exchange so unsure of the processes.  I'll leave it to more senior members to handle.

Comment: I'm also new (on this site), but how can you improve and learn if you don't try?

Comment: ... because I need to read up on what you meant in your previous email.  I'll get there eventually!

Comment: If you need any help, you can always ask.

Comment: Thank you, but no.  I feel I got reeled into this exchange [with the best intentions on Ismael's part] and need to stop right HERE!

Comment: What do you mean with "I feel I got reeled into this exchange"? Did I offended you in any way? If so, it wasn't my intention. And I'm really sorry about it. I just wanted to help you to improve your answer.

Comment: First, apologies to the moderators who asked me earlier *not* to get into chats on this site.  Ismael, I guess you didn't see that request, so it now looks like my previous comment was directed at you. Bottom line: I gave an answer that should've been a comment.  You suggested I 'incorporate' someone else's answer and I felt awkward doing that, as a newbie.  You then tried to be helpful, and no, no offence taken.  I just didn't want to get into an exchange about correct procedure when I'm still watching how it's done.  All the best, Dave.

Comment: Actually, you got it all wrong. I was trying to motivate you to improve your answer. I would do it myself, but the edit would be massively rejected. Yes, it should have been a comment, but your answer is really close to become a complete answer.

Comment: Of course, "Max Headroom" is also the name of a character in his eponymous TV show.  Short-lived but "edgy".